# regex to extract last string and integer before slash in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I got stuck with the following problem. I want to extract last string before slash limited by dash as a variable name and last integer before that slash also limited by dash as a value of this variable.

In other words I want to rewrite this imaginary url

http://www.example.com/en/golden-watch-omega-ser-3-712-p/

to

http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=en&p=712

The string is dynamic, therefore there could be "x" instead of "p", or any other letter.

Is that even possible? I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/.*-(\d+)-([a-z])/?$ index.php?lang=$1&$3=$2
```

Comment: That's it... Thank you very much.